# Getting google search result for android application

Tags: android, search

I googled this for quiet a bit tonight and haven't really came across a good solution.

I simply needed to run a query on google and retrieve the top, say 10 results. Right now the only information I need is the URL of the top 10 results. It seems like Google puts a lot of limitations if you want the results returned as in xml, unless you're a paid customer. So what's my best option here? Simply GET the html of the "http://google.com/search?q=" and try to parse it out manually? Is there a better method of doing so?